# How do I calculate a line segment that is a certain number of degrees from another line segment?

Tags: unity, c#, 3d

I have a line segment that is at an arbitrary angle in 3D space. I want to (in code) draw another line that shares an end point with the first line and has an angle of arbitrary degrees between them. The second line will partially overlap the first in the XZ plane.

Comment: What do you mean with "has an angle of X degrees between them"? What are "them" in that sentence? Maybe a drawing could help to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: Let's say 15 degrees. I want to draw a line that shares an end point with another line and meets the other line at an angle of 15 degrees. It angles in the y direction so if you viewed it from the top you would only see one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this...

```
struct LineSegment {
    public Vector3 start;
    public Vector3 end;

    public LineSegment(Vector3 start, Vector3 end) {
        this.start = start; this.end = end;
    }
}

public LineSegment LiftByAngle(LineSegment original, float angleDegrees) {
    // Compute an arrow pointing along the line segment, from start to end.
    var offset = original.end - original.start;

    // Pick a vector in the XZ plane perpendicular to our original line.
    var axis = Vector3.Cross(offset, Vector3.up);

    // Form a rotation about this axis, lifting our line upward off the XZ plane.
    var rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angleDegrees, axis);

    // Create a new line segment with the same starting point, and rotated span.
    return new LineSegment(original.start, original.start + (rotation * offset));
}
```